# Hadoop namenode and tasktracker stops working

Tags: hadoop

I had Hadoop 3 node cluster which works perfectly. Next day the namenode and jobtracker stops working and the datanode and tasktracker working continuously . After starting the hadoop it works for that day , Next day i am having same problem.
Every day i am starting the cluster.

Comment: There is no issues with the code.  Yesterday i execute the job successfully . To day morning the namenode and jobtracker is not in running mode . Everyday its happening

Comment: do you have all your metadata intact??

Comment: Can you paste the last lines of the name node and job tracker logs prior to them failing?

Comment: I dont know the time may be in night time. There are no error logs in the namenode and jobtracker log files.